# Will using "yes" command in unix waste lot of cpu cycles?

Tags: unix

Will using "yes" command waste lot of cpu cycles ?

I have a long running script (script code not in my control) which accepts something as input just once.  Then the script runs for long time . 
To automate I use "yes" command to feed the input

yes hello | myscript

Will  yes command steal/waste lot of cpu cycles ?. As per  the docs i read it keeps printing the string argument to piped program

I gave top command , i didnt see "yes" there in top

Comment: You've just answered your question.

Comment: It's upsetting that I can't answer `yes` to this question.

Comment: @wlangstroth: try `yes n` ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yes` will print the string "hello" when it has the chance - this means that the receiving end (your script) must be waiting for I/O (i.e., expecting input). So: no, `yes` does not take any CPU when the receiving end does not wait for input, the process is blocked.

See the run state of the process `yes` in a `ps auxf` for confirmation.